# ReactJS and immutability

Tags: reactjs, immutability

I've learning ReactJS for a while now. One of the thing that puzzles me is why ReactJS uses immutability in many aspects like props, elements etc. Is there any specific reason for this? What is the philosophy behind this?

When I try to add new property to `props` I'm getting the below error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Can't add property me, object is not extensible**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React uses immutability for obvious performance reasons.
For example

Idea is whenever you are setting a state , you dont mutate a state but you clone a part of it and then update the state

For example

```
this.state = {
entries: [1,2,3]
}
```

you should do

```
this.state.setState({
entries: this.state.entries.slice().push(9); //not this.state.entries.push(9)
})
```

Performance gains are achieved when you use shouldComponentUpdate

in shouldComponentUpdate you can just compare the references and not due deep checking

```
shouldComponentUpdate(prevState,newState){
  return prevState.entries != newState.entries

}
```

Comment: Can you little more describe what performance gains we really achieve here?

Comment: In this particular example, probably not much, considering the data size and the lack of other components. In a larger application with a multiple trees of components having any single component tree not update when the state changes can greatly increase application performance during a re-render.

Answer (score 5):

The philosophy behind this is one way data flow — data flows down (from top level to leaf components) and actions flow up.

A component receives its data from props, and to change something, it has to call into its parent and ask it to change something — via a callback function usually.

You can read more about it on the [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) page of the official website, it explains the concept pretty well.

Comment: I'd like to add that unidirectional data flow is much more predictable than two-way bindings. The latter may be easier to understand conceptually, but the former wins out with ease of debugging/predictability.